# Why does this usage of "it" sound awkward?

Tags: coordination

A student was asked, "According to the passage about eyeglasses above [omitted], what kind of frames would look best on a man with a round face?"

The answer key gave these as sample answers:

1. He would be [I would prefer *look*] best in angular or square
   frames.
2. It's best to choose angular or square frames.
3. Angular or square frames are the best for him.

The student answered, "It is angular or square frames."

What's the best way to explain why this answer sounds so awkward?

Comment: Would anyone care to explain why this question is being downvoted? It generated a lot of discussion among my colleagues. I've read the How to Ask page and I can't see why this doesn't fit (it's not a request for proofreading, but a request for an explanation of why something is considered incorrect).

Answer (score 0):

My suspicion is that two issues are going on at the same time:

1. *Frames* (from the question) is plural while *it* is singular
2. The answer doesn't match the tense of the question

Correcting both these yields the more natural "They would be angular or square frames."